# Type of SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I just need to know, how can I identify the type of SSRS report from Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012?

For Example: Whether the existing report is table(tablix) or matrix report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `tablix` or a `matrix` report in any version of SSRS post 2005. Each report can have charts, tables, matrices, etc all on the one report.

The only way you can know what is contained in the report is to open it and have a look.

Comment: agreed and just as an extra note. a "matrix" is just a "table" with row and column groups.